# Calling methods on like objects in a loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Lets suppose I have 4 objects:

- stringItem1
- stringItem2
- stringItem3
- stringItem4

I want to use a method that is implemented by each of them called `setText(String argument)`. I'm wondering if it's possible to call the method for each object using a loop.  Instead of saying the number of the object (`stringItem1`, or `stringItem4`), I would like to let for the loop to do it, like this:

```
for(int x=1; x<=4; x++){    
    stringItemx.setText("LOL");
}
```

Comment: You'll want to investigate [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: Why does this question deserve a downvote? Please comment.

Comment: This is incomprehensible.  It doesn't make sense.  The terminology is wrong: the question shows a fundamental misunderstanding of multiple technical terms.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you hold them in an array.
Like this:

```
StringItem[] items = new StringItem[4];
items[0] = stringItem1;
//etc...
for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
   items[i].setText("LOL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array of your string item objects, and then you can refer to them by their index.

```
JTextField[] stringItems = {stringItem1, stringItem2, /* ... */, stringItem10};
```

Later, you can use a `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringItems.length; i++) {
    stringItems[i].setText("LOL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

Instead, you can store the data in a `Map<String, YourObject>`, use the *name* of the variable as key and retrieve the elements from the `Map` with the key to apply the values:

```
Map<String, YourObject> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("stringItem1", stringItem1);
map.put("stringItem2", stringItem2);
//...
map.put("stringItem10", stringItem10);
for(int x=1;x<=10;x++){
    map.get("stringItem" + x).setText("LOL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, because `stringItemx` isn't declared in this context. You'll get an error.

You might consider using some other parameter or another similarity among these 4 objects. Because this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

No. You would have to create an array for your objects and you can go through each object by parsing through the array.